# Adding days to a date, while not exceeding the last day of the year

Tags: php, date

First of all, I'm really sorry if my english is not good !

I need to add 90 days to a the first day of the current month, but not exceed the last day of the year.

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+90 days"));
```

For exemple, if I have 01/12/2019 I need to get 31/12/2019, but I'm obviously getting 09/03/2020.

What can I do about it ? I really don't know how to do

Thank you !

Comment: If the date is greater than the last day of the year, change it to be the last day of the year. It's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `min()` to get the minimum of the +90 days or Dec 31st...

```
$date = date('d/m/Y', min(strtotime('Dec 31'), strtotime("+90 days")));
```